# Is there any way to see the component api from the html template in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm creating components but I find myself referring back to the implementation of components to use them in my app, is there any way to see the input and output properties of a component along with their types within the app.component.html?

I did a quick google search but nothing is returning, I suspect because what I'm asking for doesn't exist or I just don't know the name of it.

**Edit**
I'm working in VS code
I do have angular language service, I am using it incorrectly to see the inputs and outputs of a component, attached is a screenshot of me hovering over one of my components that has an input and it is not showing any of the inputs or outputs.

[image: app-banner]

Comment: did you add angular language service extension ?? https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Comment: Using VS code I don’t think so but if you want a more sophisticated indexer try out WebStorm. It’ll show you all the input, output and so much more when looking at different html elements and custom components.